# How would I use the Python library "Wikipedia" to extract German articles?

Tags: python, nlp, wikipedia, corpus

Using Python 2.7 in Anaconda.

I am trying to build a text corpus using only German Wikipedia articles. What would be the easiest way to extract these and save them as raw text files?

My attempt is using the Wikipedia python library:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/

https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#wikipedia.random

My idea so far is as such:

**Get a list of random wikipedia titles:**

```
import wikipedia
wikipedia.languages("DE")
titles = {}
for i in range(1, 3000):

    titles[i] = wikipedia.random(pages=page)
```

**Extract content from every title page and append to the list "test":**

```
test = []
for n in range(1,3000):
    test.append[n] = wikipedia.page(title=titles[n],auto_suggest=True,    redirect=True).content.encode('utf-8')
```

**Write the list to a text file:**

```
text_file = open("C:/Users/Cedric     Oeldorf/Desktop/University/Research/Data/Gutenberg/wiki/TEST.txt", "w")
text_file.write(test)
text_file.close()
```

I'm stuck on the second loop. I get a variety of errors ranging from Connection error to

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
```

When I run this line alone:

```
wikipedia.page(title=titles[1],auto_suggest=True, redirect=True).content.encode('utf-8')
```

It returns:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
import wikipedia
wikipedia.languages("de")
titles = {}
for i in range(500, 30000):

    titles[i] = wikipedia.random(pages=page)
    print(i,"titles retrieved")

test = {}
dictlist = []
dictlist = titles.values()
for n in range(1,30000):
    test[n] = wikipedia.summary(title=dictlist[n],auto_suggest=True,  redirect=True).encode('utf-8')

daa = []
daa = test.values()

for i in range(0,29999):
    text_file = open("C:/Users/Cedric Oeldorf/Desktop/University/Research/Data/Gutenberg/wiki/TEST2.txt", "a")
    text_file.write(daa[i])
    text_file.close()
```

I changed the for loop objects to dictionaries. I now don't get any errors.